# Changing contents of the certificate, does not corrupt pinning

Tags: android, ssl, x509certificate, pinning

I have a certificate and I would like to pin my certificate.
After I have pinned my certificate with `HttpsURLConnection` I get the response successfully, what bothers me is that,

When I change the content of the crt certificate, It does not give me any errors and still makes the connection with the host and returns the content.

How can I check if my certificate pinning works on android ?, I followed this guide to implement,
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning

Thank you :)